# android screens Navigation on back button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have 3 screens(xmls):

1. **screen 1** is main menu,
2. **screen 2** is main game and
3. **screen 3** is showing either game over screen or game finished, screen 3's background is blurred transparent on top of screen 2.

All these navigations are creating new activity(view) and using intent to go next screen.

**problem1 :** if i keep on creating new activities whenever user go to screen 1 to screen 2 and finishes the game and screen 3 will have option to new game which will create new activity of screen 2, in this case, stack will be more and to go out of the game user should press back button in more number (stack numbers). I would like to know though game creates multiple activities, in stack only 3 screens should retain (or when  user clicks on back button 3 times, game should come out)

**problem2:** user clicks on backbutton when blurred screen 3 on top of screen2 should go to main screen (screen1), as per current stage, when i click on back button its going to screen2 (from blurred screen3, which is no meaning for me)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1 :** write  `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for each activity tag in manifest . this will avoid creation of multiple instances into history stack , will keep latest entry only .

**Problem 2**  write `android:noHistory="true"` in Screen2 activity tag of manifest,so that there will be no entry for Screen2 in history stack and back press on screen3 will show screen 1 . also have a look of  [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is set the launch mode for these activites to single top in your manifest. In your manifest set `android:launchMode=singleTop` for each activity you only want one instance of. For more information, checkout [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).